# Storing data into SQLite or parsing them from internet?

Tags: android

Let's say I have 50.000 record `string` data and I am confused about using parsing way or storing them into `sqlite`.

- App needs internet connection in both cases.
- Data may change therefore If i store data into sqlite It may be
  difficult than parsing from internet.
- If I use fist way whih is storing data into `sqlite`, my app size will be a bit bigger.

I'm new to `android` and I'm looking for help about which way should I use.

Comment: The 3 points in your question seem to give you the perfect answer. Looks like [you asked the Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and got your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on the importance of the resource being time and memory

If you choose parsing data then it will take more time compared to sqlite
If you choose sqlite the it will take more memory in the device

So it depends on which resource do you prioritise more time or memory

I do have another solution
You can use both of them together

i.e. store data in database when there is no internet connection
once internet connection is available you can store data to the api from database and delete data from database

Hope this helps you to build your app